# Is there a penalty for using `@import "compass/css3"` instead of `@import "compass/css3/border-radius"`?

Tags: compass-sass

I have a sass file with

```
@import "compass/css3/border-radius";
@import "compass/css3/box-shadow";
```

I just found out that replacing that with

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

also works.

Is there any reason not to use the latter form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the import pulls in something other than mixins, the only overhead will be at compile time, when the sass compiler has to keep track of a lot more mixins—but computers are good at that sort of thing, so I wouldn't sweat it.

The caveat there are for things like `@import "compass/reset";`, which imports a big chunk of reset styles. This also doesn't have very much of a performance impact, but it does add styles to your stylesheet, which changes the output. The styles are inserted at the point you import, so be careful when importing anything that isn't a mixin later in your `.scss` file, as [later CSS rules of equal specificity trump earlier ones](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order).

But the real answer, as always, is to try a minimal `.scss` file with the import and see what CSS comes out the other end. In the end, that CSS is what you're giving the browser. Make sure it's kosher!

Comment: `compass watch` called the css `identical` after detecting the change.